# Display inline-grid not working in WordPress pages

Tags: javascript, wordpress, css, css-grid

I created a working portfolio web page (HTML/CSS) and it displays successfully locally. But when I transfer the code parts to a WordPress page I've prepared, it only displays in a single left-aligned column.

Here is the WordPress page in question: https://erichepperle.com/portfolio/

#### A screenshot of how the site display is broken

[image: A screenshot of how the site display is broken, showing one left aligned column]

I've been troubleshooting the CSS and if it is specificity issue, I've not found it.

I think it may be related to WordPress adding

tags after every section element. Why is it doing that? I've tried about 5 different suggestions on ways to strip P tags and ***none of them worked***

#### A screenshot of working section  a simple one-page local .htm file

[image: A screenshot of working section grid-array-gallery display in a simple one-page local htm file]

What is preventing proper alignment on my page and how can I fix it?

### My Code

```css
.project {
    border: solid black 2px;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    /* float: left; */
    /* display: block; */
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 20vw;
    background: wheat;
    border-radius: .6em;
    min-width: 250px;
    margin: 0 1em .4em;
    display: inline-grid;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"><header>
<h3>Web Design Portfolio:</h3>
</header>
<div id="content"><section class="project"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-6246" src="https://erichepperle.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/sm_erich-hepperle-web-design-portfolio-hepkatorganics-011.png" alt="" width="198" height="133" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle Designs Client: Hepkat Organics" href="https://hepkatorganics.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Hepkat Organics</a> |</li>
  <li>2017 |</li>
  <li>WordPress (self-hosted)</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Created web presence</li>
  <li>E-commerce</li>
  <li>Blog</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-6243 size-full" src="https://erichepperle.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/sm_erich-hepperle-web-design-portfolio-dsrfarms-011.png" alt="" width="198" height="123" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle Designs Client: DSR Farms" href="http://ehepperle.com/portfolio/dsrfarms/2017-05-01/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">DSR Farms</a> |</li>
  <li>2017 |</li>
  <li>WordPress (self-hosted)</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="size-full wp-image-6247 aligncenter" src="https://erichepperle.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/sm_erich-hepperle-web-design-portfolio-jjjfarm-011.png" alt="" width="198" height="123" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle Designs Client: Triple J Farms" href="http://ehepperle.com/portfolio/jjjfarms/2017-05-02/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">JJJ Farms</a> |</li>
  <li>2017 |</li>
  <li>WordPress (self-hosted)</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="size-full wp-image-6259 aligncenter" src="https://erichepperle.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/sm_eric-hepperle-web-design-portfolio-graywolf-011.png" alt="" width="198" height="123" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle CAS215 Course Final Project: The Gray Wolf Sanctuary" href="http://ehepperle.com/other/assignments/pcc-cas215-final/index.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">CAS215</a> |</li>
  <li>2016 |</li>
  <li>Hand-Coded</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="proj-img" src="http://ehepperle.com/other/misc-images/sm_erichepperle-webdesign-portfolio-phttours-1.png" alt="alt goes here" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle CAS206 Course Final Project: Portland Historical Tours" href="http://ehepperle.com/other/assignments/pcc-cas206-final/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">CAS206</a> |</li>
  <li>2016 |</li>
  <li>Hand-Coded</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="proj-img" src="http://ehepperle.com/other/misc-images/sm_erichepperle-webdesign-portfolio-ehw-1.png" alt="alt goes here" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle Designs Client: Eric L. Hepperle's Personal Website" href="https://erichepperle.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Eric L. Hepperle</a> |</li>
  <li>2017 |</li>
  <li>WordPress (self-hosted)</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="proj-img" src="http://ehepperle.com/other/misc-images/sm_erichepperle-webdesign-portfolio-naec-1.png" alt="alt goes here" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle Designs Client: Native American Entertainment Coalition" href="http://ehepperle.com/portfolio/naec/2017-06-16/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Native American Entertainment Coalition</a> |</li>
  <li>2017 |</li>
  <li>WordPress (self-hosted)</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="proj-img" src="http://ehepperle.com/other/misc-images/sm_erichepperle-webdesign-portfolio-goodroots-1.png" alt="alt goes here" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle Designs Client: Good Roots Community Food Bank &amp; Garden" href="http://ehepperle.com/portfolio/goodroots/2017-07-08/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Good Roots Community Food Bank &amp; Garden</a> |</li>
  <li>2017 |</li>
  <li>WordPress (self-hosted)</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="proj-img" src="http://ehepperle.com/other/misc-images/sm_erichepperle-webdesign-portfolio-handfasting2-1.png" alt="alt goes here" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle CAS213 Course Project: Eric &amp; Kat's Handfasting Cermony Website Design" href="http://ehepperle.com/other/assignments/pcc-cas213-week-7/week7.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">CAS213</a> |</li>
  <li>2016 |</li>
  <li>Hand-Coded</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="proj-img" src="http://ehepperle.com/other/misc-images/sm_erichepperle-webdesign-portfolio-pacmanfaq-1.png" alt="alt goes here" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle CAS213 Course Project: Pac-Man FAQ Webpage Design" href="http://ehepperle.com/other/assignments/pcc-cas213-week-4/week4.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">CAS213</a> |</li>
  <li>2016 |</li>
  <li>Hand-Coded</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="proj-img" src="http://ehepperle.com/other/misc-images/sm_erichepperle-webdesign-portfolio-archangels-1.png" alt="alt goes here" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle CAS213 Course Project: Archangels Website Design" href="http://ehepperle.com/other/assignments/pcc-cas213-week-3/week3.htm" target="_blank" rel="noopener">CAS213</a> |</li>
  <li>2016 |</li>
  <li>Hand-Coded</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="proj-img" src="http://ehepperle.com/other/misc-images/sm_erichepperle-webdesign-portfolio-reflections-1.png" alt="alt goes here" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle CAS 206 Course Project: Reflections on HTML5 &amp; CSS3 Webpage Design" href="http://ehepperle.com/other/assignments/pcc-cas206-reflection/reflection.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">CAS206</a> |</li>
  <li>2016 |</li>
  <li>Hand-Coded</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

</div>
<!-- END #content div -->

<footer>
<div class="copyright">Copyright © 2018 Eric Hepperle</div>
<a href="mailto:ehepp.devmail+portfolio@gmail.com">Eric Hepperle - Webmaster</a>

</footer></div>
<!-- END #wrapper div -->
```

Comment: #content is supposed to be the grid container , .project are the children to be spread into the grid (they can themself be a grid too , but obviously not the case here ). #content could also be a flex container with wrapping set. Can you clarify ?

Comment: @G-Cyr Yes, the #content is a container div and .project sections are the children. The children should display in rows and automatically wrap responsively.  It works on my computer, but not in my WordPress site. Here is the page in question: https://erichepperle.com/portfolio/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox to position your boxes.

Wrap content in some container (in your case it's #container) and give this:

```
#content {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Works for me now. You can find more information about flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: The flexbox solution worked after I removed the "align-items: center". Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all the problems are caused by the images. I wrote css for img and it was fixed. You can make the dimensions of the pictures constant. Like me.

```html
<html>
    <style>
        .project {
    border: solid black 2px;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    /* float: left; */
    /* display: block; */
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 20vw;
    background: wheat;
    border-radius: .6em;
    min-width: 250px;
    margin: 0 1em .4em;
    display: inline-grid;
}
img{
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
        </style>
<div id="wrapper"><header>
<h3>Web Design Portfolio:</h3>
</header>
<div id="content"><section class="project"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-6246" src="https://erichepperle.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/sm_erich-hepperle-web-design-portfolio-hepkatorganics-011.png" alt="" width="198" height="133" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle Designs Client: Hepkat Organics" href="https://hepkatorganics.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Hepkat Organics</a> |</li>
  <li>2017 |</li>
  <li>WordPress (self-hosted)</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Created web presence</li>
  <li>E-commerce</li>
  <li>Blog</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-6243 size-full" src="https://erichepperle.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/sm_erich-hepperle-web-design-portfolio-dsrfarms-011.png" alt="" width="198" height="123" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle Designs Client: DSR Farms" href="http://ehepperle.com/portfolio/dsrfarms/2017-05-01/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">DSR Farms</a> |</li>
  <li>2017 |</li>
  <li>WordPress (self-hosted)</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="size-full wp-image-6247 aligncenter" src="https://erichepperle.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/sm_erich-hepperle-web-design-portfolio-jjjfarm-011.png" alt="" width="198" height="123" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle Designs Client: Triple J Farms" href="http://ehepperle.com/portfolio/jjjfarms/2017-05-02/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">JJJ Farms</a> |</li>
  <li>2017 |</li>
  <li>WordPress (self-hosted)</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="size-full wp-image-6259 aligncenter" src="https://erichepperle.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/sm_eric-hepperle-web-design-portfolio-graywolf-011.png" alt="" width="198" height="123" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle CAS215 Course Final Project: The Gray Wolf Sanctuary" href="http://ehepperle.com/other/assignments/pcc-cas215-final/index.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">CAS215</a> |</li>
  <li>2016 |</li>
  <li>Hand-Coded</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="proj-img" src="http://ehepperle.com/other/misc-images/sm_erichepperle-webdesign-portfolio-phttours-1.png" alt="alt goes here" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle CAS206 Course Final Project: Portland Historical Tours" href="http://ehepperle.com/other/assignments/pcc-cas206-final/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">CAS206</a> |</li>
  <li>2016 |</li>
  <li>Hand-Coded</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="proj-img" src="http://ehepperle.com/other/misc-images/sm_erichepperle-webdesign-portfolio-ehw-1.png" alt="alt goes here" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle Designs Client: Eric L. Hepperle's Personal Website" href="https://erichepperle.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Eric L. Hepperle</a> |</li>
  <li>2017 |</li>
  <li>WordPress (self-hosted)</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="proj-img" src="http://ehepperle.com/other/misc-images/sm_erichepperle-webdesign-portfolio-naec-1.png" alt="alt goes here" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle Designs Client: Native American Entertainment Coalition" href="http://ehepperle.com/portfolio/naec/2017-06-16/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Native American Entertainment Coalition</a> |</li>
  <li>2017 |</li>
  <li>WordPress (self-hosted)</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="proj-img" src="http://ehepperle.com/other/misc-images/sm_erichepperle-webdesign-portfolio-goodroots-1.png" alt="alt goes here" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle Designs Client: Good Roots Community Food Bank &amp; Garden" href="http://ehepperle.com/portfolio/goodroots/2017-07-08/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Good Roots Community Food Bank &amp; Garden</a> |</li>
  <li>2017 |</li>
  <li>WordPress (self-hosted)</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="proj-img" src="http://ehepperle.com/other/misc-images/sm_erichepperle-webdesign-portfolio-handfasting2-1.png" alt="alt goes here" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle CAS213 Course Project: Eric &amp; Kat's Handfasting Cermony Website Design" href="http://ehepperle.com/other/assignments/pcc-cas213-week-7/week7.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">CAS213</a> |</li>
  <li>2016 |</li>
  <li>Hand-Coded</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="proj-img" src="http://ehepperle.com/other/misc-images/sm_erichepperle-webdesign-portfolio-pacmanfaq-1.png" alt="alt goes here" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle CAS213 Course Project: Pac-Man FAQ Webpage Design" href="http://ehepperle.com/other/assignments/pcc-cas213-week-4/week4.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">CAS213</a> |</li>
  <li>2016 |</li>
  <li>Hand-Coded</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="proj-img" src="http://ehepperle.com/other/misc-images/sm_erichepperle-webdesign-portfolio-archangels-1.png" alt="alt goes here" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle CAS213 Course Project: Archangels Website Design" href="http://ehepperle.com/other/assignments/pcc-cas213-week-3/week3.htm" target="_blank" rel="noopener">CAS213</a> |</li>
  <li>2016 |</li>
  <li>Hand-Coded</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->

<section class="project">
<img class="proj-img" src="http://ehepperle.com/other/misc-images/sm_erichepperle-webdesign-portfolio-reflections-1.png" alt="alt goes here" />
<ul class="horz-info">
  <li><a title="Eric Hepperle CAS 206 Course Project: Reflections on HTML5 &amp; CSS3 Webpage Design" href="http://ehepperle.com/other/assignments/pcc-cas206-reflection/reflection.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">CAS206</a> |</li>
  <li>2016 |</li>
  <li>Hand-Coded</li>
</ul>
<h5 class="proj-description">Description:</h5>
<ul>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
  <li>Service</li>
</ul>
</section><!-- End section -->
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are misunderstanding the problem, I think. The #content is a container div and .project sections are the children. The children should display in rows and automatically wrap responsively. It works on my computer, but not in my WordPress site. Here is the page in question: erichepperle.com/portfolio